# Two non-vanishing analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some trouble while solving an exercise in Conway's book Functions of one complex variable.

The problem is : Suppose that both $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic on $\bar{B}(0,R)$ with $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ for $|z|=R$. Show that if neither $f$ nor $g$ vanishes in $\bar{B}(0,R)$ then there is a constant $\lambda$, $|\lambda|=1$ such that $f=\lambda g$.

I've tried to apply the maximum modulus theorem to $h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ but, I can't handle the case that $g$ has a zero on $|z|=R$.

Any hint or answer would be appreciated

Comment: Don't You assume that  $g$ has no zeros in the closure of $B(0,R)$? Therefore, this function does not have zeros on the boundary  $|z| = R$.

Comment: How can I assume that $g$ has no zeros in the closure of &B(0,R)&?

Comment: What does "neither $f$ nor $g$ vanishes on $\bar B (0,R)$" mean?

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ has a zero on $|z|=R$, then $f$ is there $0$ as well.

Therefore, you can omit the zeros of $g$ because $f=\lambda g$ is true at the zeros of $g$ for every $\lambda$. $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ for $|z|=R$ implies $\lambda=1$, unless $f(z)=g(z)=0$ for $|z|=R$, which implies that $f$ and $g$ vanish, which is excluded.

For more details, look here :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: But how can I get to the conclusion &f=\lambda g&??

Comment: @user88914 What are you thinking? $0 = \lambda \times 0$ is obvious.

Comment: I mean, how can we use maximum modulus theorem?

Comment: Please give me more details. If you don't mind