# Use the Maximum modulus principle and the zeros of an analytic function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, open-map

Let $f$ and $g$ be analytic on a connected open set $U$. Assume that the closed disc $\overline{D(z_0,r)}$ is contained in $U$, where $r$ is a positive number. Show that if $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ on the circle $|z-z_0|=r$ then there is a constant $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$ such that $f=\lambda g$ on $U$.

Use the Maximum modulus principle and the zeros of an analytic function.

Comment: $f(z) = 1$, $g(z) = z$ is a counterexample on the unit disk.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? 
Here is a similar problem you can check out 
[Two non-vanishing analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949236/two-non-vanishing-analytic-functions)

It would seem that you need an additional assumption on the vanishing part.